# Which is better approach for modeling?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm

```
all['Area_Type'].value_counts()

DownTown              5577
MidTownResidential    1083
CityLimits             935
Industrial             928
Name: Area_Type, dtype: int64
```

These are the value counts of a column named Area_Type. Is it better to create dummies for this categorical variable or to convert them into numeric using this

```
all['Area_Type']=all['Area_Type'].map({"DownTown":1,
                                       "MidTownResidential":2, 
                                       "CityLimits":3,
                                       "Industrial":4})
```

Which is more feasible. And how do both affect the working of the algorithms while modeling?

Comment: If the there is some sense of order or rank among the categories, mapping them to that scale seems like a better option

Comment: This highly depends on what you need to do, and if a records can have on more multiple Area types. I agreed with @yatu, if there a sense of Rank, better to scale, them, if this an input for a machine learning algorithm, better to `get_dummies`, memory saving, scale again, so, it depends.